# How to add Maven dependencies from different repositories

Tags: java, maven-2

For example, let's say I have a Maven build file that has dependencies located in two different repositories:

```all
<repository>
    <id>id1</id>
    <name>id1</name>
    <url>http://localhost/mavenRepo/repository1</url>
</repository>

<repository>
    <id>id2</id>
    <name>id2</name>
    <url>http://localhost/mavenRepo/repository2</url>
</repository>
```

With one dependencies from the first repository and the other from the second repository. How can I do this?

Comment: I thought I was doing it right. Basically after a bunch more troubleshooting I found it was something completely unrelated. It's just that when I added the second repo that's when it failed. I went down the wrong trail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just list all the dependencies in your `<dependencies>` section, and Maven will contact each repository in turn (including your local repository) to find them.

A POM file has no concept of "get these dependencies from this repository and get these dependencies from that repository".

Comment: How are dependencies resolved with multiple repositories? I have defined one private repository in init.gradle, but maven is trying to get them from maven central

Answer (score 2):

How can you do what? What is the problem? Just add the dependencies and Maven will try to resolve them from *central* repository and then fallback on the next declared repository if not found and so on.